# ssms --- how create one table on one server using 2 tables on another server

Tags: ssms

I need to create a table on a server using 2 tables from another server.

Source server
Table definitions for the below Table 1 and Table 2 are same
Table 1 ---- col 1, col2, col3
Table 2 ---- col4, col5, col6

Destination server
Table 3 --- data should be union of Table 1 and Table 2 data

How to do this? Thanks.

Comment: You're question isn't clear. Please provide more details and what you have so far.

Comment: edited the contents. Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So I created a test database named `EmptyDatabase` and `Table1`, `Table2` as well:

[image]

Then, according to your needs, I created a dynamic query that will produce this output: `CREATE TABLE dbo.Table3 (col1 varchar(50),col2 int,col3 decimal,col4 varchar(50),col5 int,col6 decimal)` and will be excecuted with `sp_executesql`:

```
USE [EmptyDatabase]

-- Declare a temp table to store column names from Table 1 and 2.
DECLARE @TableColumns TABLE
(
    RowNumber int IDENTITY(1,1),
    TableName varchar(50),
    ColumnName varchar(50),
    DataType varchar(50),
    Lenght integer
)

-- Query 'Table1' column names and insert them into the @TableColumns table.
INSERT INTO @TableColumns
    SELECT
        'Table1' AS TableName,
        COLUMN_NAME,
        DATA_TYPE,
        CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    FROM
        [EmptyDatabase].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        TABLE_NAME = N'Table1'

-- Query 'Table2' column names and insert them into the @TableColumns table.
INSERT INTO @TableColumns
    SELECT
        'Table2' AS TableName,
        COLUMN_NAME,
        DATA_TYPE,
        CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH
    FROM
        [EmptyDatabase].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE
        TABLE_NAME = N'Table2'

-- Count total rows.
DECLARE @id int
DECLARE @totalrows int = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TableColumns)
DECLARE @currentrow int = 1

-- Declare variables to query the row's data.
DECLARE @columnName varchar(50)
DECLARE @dataType varchar(50)
DECLARE @lenght int

-- Declare the custom string to construct your dynamic query.
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX)

-- Start creating your dinamic query.
SET @query = 'CREATE TABLE dbo.Table3 ('

-- Iterate through the results.
WHILE @currentrow <=  @totalrows  
BEGIN 
    -- Get the current row's data.
    SET @columnName = (SELECT ColumnName FROM @TableColumns WHERE RowNumber = @currentrow)
    SET @dataType = (SELECT DataType FROM @TableColumns WHERE RowNumber = @currentrow)
    SET @lenght = (SELECT Lenght FROM @TableColumns WHERE RowNumber = @currentrow)

    -- Add column declaration.
    SET @query += @columnName + ' ' + @dataType 

    -- If its a char type add its lenght.
    IF @dataType = 'varchar'
    BEGIN
        SET @query += '(' + CAST(@lenght AS VARCHAR) + ')'
    END

    -- Add a comma after column declaration except to the last one.
    IF @currentrow < @totalrows
    BEGIN
        SET @query += ','   
    END

    -- Next row.
    SET @currentrow += 1    
END

-- Terminate the dynamic query string.
SET @query += ')'

-- Execute the dynamic query to create the table.
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

And the table is created:

[image]

This can also be done with a `CURSOR`.